# What is Input Impedance Mismatching of differential Operational Amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, differential, impedance-matching, input-impedance

I am new to design differential op-amp.

I am not sure if my circuit will experience input impedance mismatching.

Can anyone explain how input impedance mismatching will happen in differential op-amp? How should I solve it?

Here is my circuit of differential op-amp:

[image]

Comment: It's all down to resistor tolerances and how having two supposedly "same value"  resistors at the opposite end of their tolerance range, will cause common-mode voltages to be amplified. There are plenty of web resources about this and this site providing a new one isn't really a great idea.

Comment: What should I search for  the topic that you talked about? I dont quite understand

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common-mode_rejection_ratio and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_amplifier

Comment: This is a circuit that sparks a lot of confusion regarding input impedance because the answer is different depending on whether the inputs are coming from a floating transducer or from two independent low impedance drivers. In the transducer case the same current flows through R1 and R2 and the differential impedance becomes R1+R2. Here's a nice video that explains why: [diffZ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72ynZxv7dyY/watch?v=72ynZxv7dyY). Common mode inputs see the same impedance on both legs, R2+R4 (assuming R2=R1).